# HP UFT Recovery Scenario for IE Hang

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, freeze, hp-uft, recovery

Me and a few colleagues have been trying to work around an IE Hang issue which we've been experiencing in our scripts (and manual testing as its an application issue).

Unfortunately, when IE Hangs, it causes UFT to Hang as well until the "iexplore.exe *32" process is killed. This appears to do a quick refresh of IE and lets the script continue the majority of the time.

We've been exploring with using UFT recovery scenario options to handle this however as UFT hangs when IE Hangs, UFT won't trigger the recovery scenario.

Alternatively, we have created a (windows) utilty to run in the background which check the "iexplore.exe *32" process every 10 seconds and if it is hung, will kill it.

Unfortunately, as explained before, this isnt 100% effective as it sometimes results in IE completely closing.

UFT Recovery Scenario Application Crash triggers don't appear to trigger with a killed process either so we were attempting to have it set as an "object does not exist".  How can we go about solving this using what options we have?

Thanks

Comment: See https://community.hpe.com/t5/Unified-Functional-Testing/When-will-UFT-support-IE11/td-p/6391997 . To view the Windows Event Viewer go Start>Control Panel>Administrative Tools>Event Viewer.... look for the 'Faulting Module' in the error report. Check Tools>Manage Addons>Show all addons... you will need both x86 and x64 versions enabled.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

We've figured out a way to set the windows utility to run as a service or a shell (so CMD doesn't have to stay open) to kill the process. Its about a 60-70% chance it just refreshes and the script continues. When it doesn't work, it kills the iexplore.exe sessions entirely.

We've created a recovery scenario for run errors which when triggered the function first checks whether the browser exists or not and checks a couple environment variables set within login/logoff to ensure that you're expecting a session open at the time. If these if statements are true, it opens up ie again, logs on and reruns the most previous action before continuing the script after that. (we use cases and actions in our run scripts).

The issue now is updating all of our existing run scripts (hundreds) with a new recovery scenario which HP Support have advised, does not exist as a functionality and will have to be done manually (We have submitted it as a enhancement request). We're trying to figure out a way to write it in a function or script however checking out a script, editing it and checking it in during run time doesn't appear to work as Quality Center seems to run all scripts in read-only. I'll start another thread on that.